# I get a message "local variable 'cache' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Morse encrypter, and I don't see why my code isn't working. I have a working one which I made using a tutorial, but this one and that one mainly have the samr guts.

My code:

```
cheat_sheet = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
                '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
                '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

cache = 'beans'

def morse_encrypter (placeholder):
    for letter in placeholder:
        cache += cheat_sheet [letter]
    return cache

b = input ('bruh')

def DO_THE_THING():
    placeholder = b
    the_answer = morse_encrypter(placeholder.upper())
    print (the_answer)

DO_THE_THING ()
```

Comment: Put `cache = ''` in the method morse_encrypted

Comment: thank you that worked

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code references the current value of `cache` via the `+=` operation but it's not defined. Variables used in functions are local to them by default, so you *could* fix that by adding a `cache = ''` at the very beginning in the `morse_encrypter()`.

However. the fact is you don't really need the variable at all if you instead used what is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) as shown below:

```
def morse_encrypter(placeholder):
    return ''.join(cheat_sheet[letter] for letter in placeholder)
```

There's additional information on generator expressions and related list comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) in the documentation if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> "global cache" in morse_encrypter()

This should work-

```
cheat_sheet = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
                '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
                '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

cache = 'beans'

def morse_encrypter (placeholder):
    global cache
    for letter in placeholder:
        cache += cheat_sheet [letter]
    return cache

b = input ('bruh')

def DO_THE_THING():
    placeholder = b
    the_answer = morse_encrypter(placeholder.upper())
    print (the_answer)
    DO_THE_THING ()
```

Or you can initiate a local instance of 'cache', depending on your program requirements.

Comment: Besides declaring it `gloabl`, you would also need to initialize it at the beginning of `morse_encrypter()` — so it woulbe be best to do what you suggest at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Put cache = '' in the method morse_encrypted